# ASP MongoDB Api freezes when using BSON Extra Elements tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, bson

I have an ASP.NET api to handle data going to a Mongo database. I need to also send some dynamic / irregular data for a number of documents, that'll have a couple of extra fields.

So basically I'm trying to recreate the code from this tutorial

https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.8/examples/mixing_static_and_dynamic/

but when i try to post or get the app will freeze, no errors or crashes though.

[Swagger screenshot included](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogccJ.png), this is how it freezes and the only way to unfreeze is to restart the app from VS.

The class code:

```
public class Incident
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string? Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("Name")] 
    public string? Name { get; set; }

    [BsonExtraElements]
    public BsonDocument? Additional { get; set; }
}
```

It works just fine with static fields, but due to the nature of the data the db will receive I need some dynamic fields as well. Alternatively, is there any other way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running this via postman gave me an error code:

> Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonString' to type
> 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonBoolean'.

I'll mark this as solved as this is what my original question was trying to find.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I think you enable Swagger, Swagger translate and generate the whole `BsonDocument` object(too heavy), to avoid this hang and accept to pass dynamic params to object(document) by `MongoDB.Driver` follow:

- first if you are using dotnet core, `System.Text.Json` enabled as default
- `Dictionary<string, object>` when Desterilize with object value or any type of object will be `JsonElement` [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-use-dom-utf8jsonreader-utf8jsonwriter?pivots=dotnet-6-0) and it's hard to handle all props and passing to insert by `MongoDB.Driver`,  we should serialize or `ToString` then pars to `BsonDocument`

---

#### Example

```cs
 //pass strong type
     public class Foo
    {

        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string? Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
      

        [BsonExtraElements]
        public Dictionary<string, object> Metadata { get; set; }

        public void TranslateMetadata()
        {
            if (this.Metadata is null) return;
            var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(this.Metadata);
            this.Metadata = BsonDocument.Parse(json).ToDictionary();
        }
    }

// Add
//case 1 :
 public void Add(Foo foo) {
            foo.TranslateMetadata();
            await Context1.InsertOneAsync(foo);
  }




//case2 :  pass object

    public void Add(object foo)  //object from foo
    { 
            var json = foo.ToString();
            this.Metadata = BsonDocument.Parse(json);

            await Context1.InsertOneAsync(foo);
     }
```